# Check if two arrays have been concatenated correctly in C

Tags: c, string

The following function allows me to calculate the length of a character string:

```
int arrayLen (char array[])
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( array[i] )
        ++i;

    return i;
}
```

The problem is, if an array has 20 elements but only uses, say, 5 of them (including the null character `\0`), then the function will return 5. So from this, it's difficult to know how many characters the string can support in a function. Unfortunately, `sizeof` can't be used since the array is dynamically-allocated.

---

Here is an example of the basic function I'm trying to create, it allows the user to insert a character string into another character string at the index of the `source[]`:

```
void insertString (char source[], char insert[], int index)
{
    int n = arrayLen (insert);
    char temp[n];

    // Replace characters from index with characters in insert array
    for ( i = 0; source[index + i] && insert[i]; ++i )
    {
        temp[i] = source[index + i];
        source[index + i] = insert[i];
    }

    // Concatenate replaced characters onto source array
    for ( i = 0; temp[i]; ++i )
        source[index + n + i] = temp[i];
}
```

The above code works fine until `source[]` isn't big enough to contain itself and the elements `insert[]`. Is there anyway to test for this and inform the user?

---

### Update

I understand the limitations of finding the length of an array but is there a way to check if the array has been concatenated correctly onto the `source[]`?

e.g.

`input = the wrong son`

`output = the wrong person▒▒"`

Comment: The caller will have to pass the buffer size explicitly as a parameter. (Since they allocated the buffer, they should know.) There's no (portable) way in C to get that information from a pointer.

Comment: @T.C. Could there be a way though to detect if the character strings haven't been concatenated correctly due to a lack of size in `source[]`?

Comment: C does not inherently pass the size of any arrays.

Comment: `insertString` wrong logic.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What do you mean? The function inserts the character string `insert[]` into `source[]` at the a specified `index`. Or do you mean the implementation is logically wrong?

Comment: `source` may loses its final `'\0'`.

Comment: For example, a three-character length of the string to be inserted were stored at the end of the case 3 is binding but required binding it is the rest of the string instead of three characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not passing the actual buffer size to the function, there is no way to determine its size. When you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer:

```
unsigned wrong_sizeof(char arr[])
{
    return (unsigned)sizeof arr;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "Hello world!";
    char *p;

    printf("wrong_sizeof(s): %u\n", wrong_sizeof(s));
    printf("sizeof p: %u\n", (unsigned) sizeof p);
    printf("sizeof s: %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof s);

    return 0;
}
```

That program first prints the incorrect size calculation, which is incorrect because the function `wrong_sizeof` receives a pointer to the first element of the array (`&s[0]`) instead the entire array itself. This is something the C language specification requires.

Next is the size of a pointer using the `sizeof` operator directly, followed by the size of the array using the `sizeof` operator directly instead of the function. This proves that the function receives a pointer.

To conclude, you must pass one of two things:

1. the size of the output buffer
2. the number of characters to copy

With either one of these, it is no longer your fault as the designer of the function if an incorrect parameter is passed because you're only doing what you're told, similar to `strncpy`, `strcat`, etc.

---

**Edit**

To address the update:

```
new_size == source_length - i + insert_size
```

The size required by the new string, including the null terminator, is the number of characters in the source string, excluding the null terminator, plus the number of characters required for storing the string to insert, including the null terminator. For example:

```
char buf[] = "Hello, world!"
insertString(buf, "John", 7);
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

will result in a new string requiring 14 - 7 + 5, or 12, characters: 7 for "Hello, " and 5 for "John\0".

Answer (score 1):

In C, you need to explicitly tell the compiler the buffer size as a parameter since all the elements in an array are not copied into the array parameter; instead they are referenced by a pointer. - [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c)

---

### Additional Info:

`sizeof array / sizeof array[0]` doesn't work since `sizeof array` references the size of the pointer to the first element in `array`, not the size of all the elements in the array. This would only work if the array was declared in the same function was the `sizeof` calculations.

You could, however, calculate how many elements are occupied in the array as follows:

```
int i = 0;
while ( array[i] )
    ++i;
```

This works if the array is ended by a null character `\0`. If the array has more space reserved than whats actually used, the above function will fail to identify that.